# Confusion about affine plane minus origin not being affine

Tags: algebraic-geometry, solution-verification

The question I am working on is

> "Show that $\mathbb{A}^2-\{(0,0)\}$ is not affine".

There are already many questions and proofs here for this, for example see: [(1)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/122821/mathbba2-not-isomorphic-to-affine-space-minus-the-origin) or [(2)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/424067/mathbba2-backslash-0-0-is-not-affine-variety).

I only have very basic knowledge of algebraic geometry and I couldn't understand some of the arguments of these proofs. I came up with the basic proof (?), but it is probably wrong seeing that the other proofs are much more involved. Can you tell me where I am wrong?

My short attempt is:

> Assume $\mathbb{A}^2-\{(0,0)\}$ is an affine variety. This means $\{(0,0)\}$ is an open set in the Zariski topology in $\mathbb{A}^2$. Open sets must be dense in Zariski topology but a single point cannot be dense, so we have a contradiction.

Comment: $\mathbb{A}^2-\{(0,0)\}$ being affine does not imply that $\{(0,0)\}$ is open.

Comment: Isn't an affine variety $(\mathbb{A}^2-\{(0,0)\})$ a closed set and so its complement $(\{(0,0)\})$ an open set?

Comment: No, that would be a closed subvariety. For example, $\mathbb{A}^1-\{0\}$ is affine because it is isomorphic to the subvariety of $\mathbb{A}^2$ defined by $XY-1$.

Comment: Thanks, now I see that my attempt does not work for $\mathbb{A}^1-\{0\}$. I am probably confused with the basic definitions and will study them again.